# Is there a tool that allows the same functionality of extend/trim feature that was available in 9.3?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, tools, extend

In ArcGIS 9.3 there was a tool called Extend/Trim Features that allowed you to select multiple segments and extend or trim them to a feature.

In 10.1 that seems to have been moved to the Production Mapping Extension at a hefty price. It was replaced by two tools that don't seem to have the same functionality as the previous versions tool.

My question: Is anybody aware of an add in or way that I could create this functionality with python or a custom tool?

**EDIT**

The old tool can be found referenced [HERE](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=trimming_lines), there is also a screenshot of the tool location from 9.3:

[image]

Essentially, it did both of the functions that are shown in @Jakub's answer.

It looks like the same tool from 9.3 was moved to the [Production Mapping toolbar](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_data_editing_in_Production_Mapping/0103000001ws000000/) in 10.1.

There seems to be an [ESRI Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bmlk&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=CityEngine&p=132) out there suggesting they bring it back, and that I'm not, in fact, imagining that it used to be this way.

Comment: Are you able to provide links to the 9.3 and 10.0 documentation for the functionality you say was removed from the core product at 10.1?

Comment: Do you mean Trim And [extend line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000004000000) or [Trim Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000008000000) ?

Comment: I have edited the question to include links and more information.

Comment: In the Customize Menu, you can set Extend and Trim to Keyboard shortcuts for easy access. Just an idea.

Answer (score 3):

The tools are in Advanced Editing toolbar. Customize->Toolbars->Advanced Editing Tools.
[image]

Comment: Yes, now it is two tools and a little more cumbersome to use, I'm wondering if there is a way to consolidate the tasks like they were in 9.3. I've edited my question to give more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about 10.1, but in 10.0 you can get the 9.3 editor toolbar including the 'Extend/Trim Features'.

1. Go to :\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\Utilities
2. Open AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe
3. Under Editor tab, UNCHECK 'Create features using templates'
4. The Editor toolbar will now look and function like in 9.3.
   [image: Advance Settings]

Answer (score 0):

At 10.1 there is a [Trim Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000008000000) and also an [Extend Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extend_Line/001v00000004000000/) geoprocessing tool.